# How to write test case for static methods and static variables using wrapper class or dependency injection

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

My requirement is need to write test case for `Example1` view model using xunit. This view model initialize the `Example2` view model. But the `Example2` contains *static* method inside the constructor and that static method contains one static variable.

If I have write a test case for `Example1`, the test cases getting failed while run all test cases but it getting passed while run selected test cases. Because of using static method inside `Example2`.

I have tried with changing the static methods and variables to non-static but its throws `System.TypeInitializationException` exception.

Can anyone explain or give example for this? Without removing the static key word how i can achieve this? can anyone please give a guidance?

example:

```
public class Example1
{
    public Example1(Example2 example2) { ... }
}   

public class Example2
{
    public Example2()
    {
        SomeStaticMethod() //static method inside the constructor
    }

    static SomeStaticMethod()
    {
        logPath = ""; //logPath is the static variable which is declared in another static class
    }
}
```

Comment: What edition of visual studio do you have? Why does it have to be `xunit`?

Answer (score 0):

If you simply need to pass an instance of `Example2` in the constructor, it is fairly simple:

```
namespace Tests
{
  using Xunit;

  using XunitSample;

  public class Class1
  {
    [Fact]
    public void Example1_Test()
    {
      var ex2 = (Example2)System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(typeof(Example2));

      var target = new Example1(ex2);

      Assert.NotNull(target);
    }
  }
}
```